# A word for a person who wants to speak, but can't due to lack of courage or lack of conviction that what he speaks is correct

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a person called when he wants to answer back criticism or insults or injustice but can't do it due to lack of courage or when he thinks too much before speaking and then repents on not having spoken at the right time or on not having put his foot forward.

Comment: Part 1: *chicken*. Part 2: *regretful*. Which part does your question focus on?

Comment: Meant the one who thinks too much before answering back assuming it would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest ***diffident***.

> Modest or shy because of a lack of self-confidence.
>
> ‘a diffident youth’

Source: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/diffident)

Comment: It's good practice to link to your reference. I've done it for you. Re-edit if you wish. Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

**timorous**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/timorous)

> Full of apprehensiveness; timid. full of or subject to fear. 
>   characterized by or indicating fear or timidity: a timorous approach
>   to a serious problem.

As in:

> I reproached myself with being so timorous and cautious — Daniel Defoe

Answer (score 1):

The first word that springs to mind is "Shy".

You could also go with "self-effacing" or "timid"

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is - shy. I also would recommend - introvert, timid or hesitant.

Comment: Elaboration and adding citations add value to answers.